# What are some solid attacks in chess?

Tags: learning

By solid attacks, I mean, attacks that have been tested over time.  They don't necessarily have to be used at the top-level. I will give an example of what I am looking for:

The `Fried Liver Attack` can be used against the `Two Knights Defense` and the `Traxler Counter Attack` can be used against the `Fried Liver Attack`.

Comment: I believe you are misusing the term "Fried Liver Attack". I think you mean it to refer to `1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 3.Nf6 4.Ng5`; however, the Fried Liver attack happens only after `4...d5 5.exd5 Nxd5 6.Nxf7`, `6.Nxf7` (the option for white is `6.d4`) is what defines the Fried Liver attack. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Knights_Defense,_Fried_Liver_Attack

Answer (score 3):

I think the Cochrane gambit is sound enough:

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 d6 4. Nxf7!?
```

Also the Evans Gambit:

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.b4
```

The Marshall counter-gambit in Ruy Lopez, sacrifices are pawn and gives black a good attack. However, it seems that some Grandmasters are using it as drawing tool, but for us black should have an attack.

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5 a6 4.Ba4 Nf6 5.O-O Be7 6.Re1 b5 7.Bb3 O-O 8.c3 d5 9.exd5 Nxd5 10.Nxe5 Nxe5 11.Rxe5
```

Comment: OK, good answer. I think my understanding of attacks is wrong. When I am thinking of attacks, I am thinking of a set of moves that have the name attack such as `Fried Liver Attack, Traxler Counter Attack, Grand Prix Attack, Lolli Attack`. Are gambits classified as one type of attack?

Comment: Opening names are pretty arbitrary, there is very little system to them. "Attack" basically means that it is an opening that white chooses to play; variations that are defined by a black move are often called "Defence". Or, rarely, "Counter Attack". But that doesn't mean that those lines are classified as something, or that they have something in common.

Comment: As @RemcoGerlich said the names are arbitrary. Any attack that includes a gambit, could very well be named `Gambit`, and I am sure there cases when an opening is referred to as both. Some openings that have a name `Attack` don't require a gambit. For example, `Austrian Attack`, `Bayonet Attack`, so `Attack` is more general.

Comment: Oh, and there is `Queen's Gambit` which is hardly a `Gambit`, the names are set arbitrarily :).